# Jeddict inside EJB project

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

Hi) i have question about this product/plagin for netbeans - https://jeddict.github.io
I have the EAR project, inside it's WEB and EJB. I try create Entities from Jeddict JPADiagramm, inside the EJB, but when I click Generate source code -> I select my EJB project -> Generate,  I get the message 
"please select the Maven  Web Applicion project for full-stacks app" 
But I do not need anything else, I just need the generate Entities from the created diagram inside my EJB project. What i do wrong? How i can reach my target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar issue is already raised : https://github.com/jeddict/jeddict/issues/263 .
New version of Jeddict with fix will be available soon.